# How to read first set of numbers between strings using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following strings and need to extract the numbers as follows :

```
1) M123123123AD123 => 123123123
2) M1231231212MN23 => 1231231212
3) G12312312312DD => 12312312312
```

I am currently reading it using `"\d+[0-9]"`. This works well if there is 1 number after the second set of characters. But if there are multiple numbers after the second character set, the above regex string picks them too. For example, '`M123123123AD123`' will give `123123123123`. But the last 123 should not be there.

Comment: I don't see the issue. This code works just fine: `var regex = new Regex(@"\d+[0-9]"); var input = "M123123123AD123"; var first = regex.Match(input).Value`. You should post your code in the question.

Comment: Your regex should be finding 2 matches, not one match with all the numbers. But maybe you want something like `"(?<=^[GM])\d+"` to anchor it to the beginning of the string with whatever letters you expect.

Comment: This will work for the examples above: `\d+[0-9](?=[A-Z])`. But as per previous comments, using your version and taking first match is cleaner.

Comment: (and this one will work in all cases, ex. _M12312312AD2342KX4323_: `(?<=^[A-Z]*)\d+`). This is called a lookbehind, previous one was a lookahead.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get a streak of digits in between two letters.

You can use

```cs
(?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%29%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%29&i=M123123123AD123%20%3D%3E%20123123123%0D%0AM1231231212MN23%20%3D%3E%201231231212%0D%0AG12312312312DD%20%3D%3E%2012312312312).

Or, if you want to get the digits after the leading non-digit chars, use

```cs
(?<=^\D+)\d+(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

See [this .NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5CD%2B%29%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%29&i=M123123123AD123%20%3D%3E%20123123123%0D%0AM1231231212MN23%20%3D%3E%201231231212%0D%0AG12312312312DD%20%3D%3E%2012312312312&o=m).

In C#, you can use `Regex.Match`:

```cs
var result = Regex.Match(text, @"(?<=^\D+)\d+(?=[a-zA-Z])")?.Value;
```

*Regex details*:

- `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` - right before the current location, there must be an ASCII letter (use `\p{L}` to match any letter)
- `(?<=^\D+)` - right before the current location, there must be start of string + any one or more non-digit chars (use `\D*` if the digits can appear at the start of string)
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?=[a-zA-Z])` - right after the current location, there must be an ASCII letter (use `\p{L}` to match any letter).